# Find cell with value, offset and copy range then paste basing data's date, then loop to findnext

Tags: excel

With th following Excel Sheet.

[image: Following is the excel]

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Find the cell with Value, let's say "Sam", in range("B17:B25")
2. Offset(0,5).resize(,8).copy
3. Find the Date value of the Data row, and paste Data to range("B4:M4") according to the data's Date.
4. Loop to find next.

Here is what I got so far, don't know how to loop:

```
Sub getDat()

Dim myFind As Range
    Dim pasteLoc As Range
    Dim payee, pasteMon As String

        Range("B5:M12").ClearContents

        With Sheet3.Cells

            payee = Range("B2").Text

            Set myFind = .Find(What:=payee, After:=Range("B16"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not myFind Is Nothing Then

                    myFind.Offset(0, 3).Resize(, 8).Copy

                    pasteMon = myFind.Offset(0, 1).Text

                    With Range("B4:M4")

                        Set pasteLoc = .Find(What:=pasteMon, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

                            If Not pasteLoc Is Nothing Then

                                pasteLoc.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

                            End If

                    End With

                End If

        End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: seems like a simple `SumProduct` or `DGET` Excel Function would be easier, if that is an option

Comment: Slai thanks for your comment, besides the excel functions do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simplified version (not tested)

```
Sub getDat()

    Range("B5:M12").ClearContents

    Dim c As Range, r As Range

    For Each c in Range("B16").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells

        If c = Range("B2") Then

            Set r = Range("B4:M4").Find(c(, 2)) 

            If Not r Is Nothing Then 

                r(2).Resize(8) = Application.Transpose(c(, 4).Resize(, 8))

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting the "Run-Time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.", what could be causing this? I'm using excel version 16. Thanks

Comment: @LeonL seems like I missed 2 letters in the `.CurrentRegion.Columns`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this **For loop** would work as well:

```
Sub getDat()
    Dim payee As String
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    payee = Range("B2").Value
    Range("B5:M12").ClearContents
            For x = 17 To lastrow
                If Cells(x, 2).Value = payee Then
                    For y = 2 To 13
                        If Cells(4, y).Value = Cells(x, 3).Value Then
                            Range("E" & x & ":L" & x).Copy
                            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, y), Cells(12, y)).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                     Next y
                End If
            Next x
 End Sub
```